# python ax window content being automatically refreshed

Tags: python, matplotlib

Known bugs are when plots the window's **plt.pause** while the thread is multithreaded, and the other thread needs windows to draw points, causing the reaction to get stuck.

- Is there any way to get the effect of plotting points in my window
  displayed dynamically, that is, the point is drawn step by step.Or
  other ways  allowing ax window content being automatically refreshed.

I think the main problem is caused by the command "plt.pause"

```
  #-*-coding:utf-8-*-
    from matplotlib.patches import Circle
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import xlrd
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
    import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
    import time
    from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox,OffsetImage
    from PIL import Image
    import random
    from time import ctime,sleep
    import threading
     #地图可视化
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines()
    ax.stock_img()
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                      linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=15, linestyle='--')
    gl.xlabels_top = False
    gl.ylabels_left = False
    gl.xlines = False
    gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-180, -45, 0, 45, 180])
    gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
    gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
    gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 15, 'color': 'gray'}
    gl.xlabel_style = {'color': 'red', 'weight': 'bold'}
    img=Image.open(r'E:\python_file\untitled\p.png')
    imagebox=OffsetImage(img,zoom=0.05)
    imagebox.image.axes=ax
    ab=AnnotationBbox(imagebox,[55,10],pad=0,frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
    ac=AnnotationBbox(imagebox,[63,0],pad=0,frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ac)
    ad=AnnotationBbox(imagebox,[70,-10],pad=0,frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ad)
    #============================================#攻击
    tolerance=1
    x_m1,y_m1=random.randint(-180,180),random.randint(-90,90)
    v_m1=170
    x_m2,y_m2=random.randint(-180,180),random.randint(-90,90)
    v_m2=v_m1
    x_m3,y_m3=random.randint(-180,180),random.randint(-90,90)
    v_m3=v_m1
    x_m4,y_m4=55,10
    x_m5,y_m5=63,0
    x_m6,y_m6=70,-10

    class target():
        """docstring for target"""
        def __init__(self, x, y):

            self.x = x
            self.y = y
    target1=target(x_m4,y_m4)
    target2=target(x_m5,y_m5)
    target3=target(x_m6,y_m6)
    v=v_m1

    class missile(threading.Thread):

        """docstring for missile"""

        def __init__(self, x, y,name):
            super(missile,self).__init__()
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.name=name
        def forward(self, v, target1):
            """docstring for forward"""
            if self.x < target1.x:
                alpha = np.arctan((target1.y - self.y) / (target1.x - self.x))
            elif self.x > target1.x:
                alpha = np.pi + np.arctan((target1.y - self.y) / (target1.x - self.x))
            elif self.x == target1.x and self.y < target1.y:
                alpha = np.pi / 2
            else:
                alpha = -np.pi / 2
            self.x = self.x + v * 0.01 * np.cos(alpha)
            self.y = self.y + v * 0.01 * np.sin(alpha)
            return self.x, self.y
        def distance(self, target1):
            """docstring for distance"""
            return np.sqrt((self.x - target1.x) ** 2 + (self.y - target1.y) ** 2)

        def run(self):

            while True:

                if self.distance(target1)<self.distance(target2) and self.distance(target1)<self.distance(target3):
                    if self.distance(target1)<tolerance:
                            print ("collision")

                            break
                    else:
                          self.x,self.y=self.forward(v,target1)

                if self.distance(target2)<self.distance(target1) and self.distance(target2)<self.distance(target3):
                    if self.distance(target2)<tolerance:
                            print ("collision")
                            break
                    else:
                          self.x,self.y=self.forward(v,target2)

                if self.distance(target3)<self.distance(target2) and self.distance(target3)<self.distance(target1):

                    if self.distance(target3)<tolerance:
                            print ("collision")


                            break
                    else:
                          self.x,self.y=self.forward(v,target3)
                print "qian jin"

                plt.plot(self.x, self.y, 'bx')
                print "ok2"
                plt.pause(0.1)#the commond
    m2=missile(x_m2,y_m2,'mm')
    m1=missile(x_m1,y_m1,'mn')
    m3=missile(x_m3,y_m3,'md')
    m1.start()
    m2.start()
    m3.start()
    plt.show()
```

these are the all codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try

```
fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

The reason for the plt.pause() is because when matplotlib plots it first generates the structure needed for the plot and then updates the screen. But if it continuously gets new data to plot it never updates the screen (to busy plotting). Therefore, pausing just a fraction of a second gives matplotlib time to update the screen. The flush_events function of the figure forces matplotlib to update the screen without the pause.

Comment: the method you suggested is very useful,thanks a lot