# i want to get some approaches to update the content of ax windows automatically in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

just mean update the content automatically from my plot command 
 I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: It is _very_ unclear what you mean. Please try and describe the problem in much more detail. Also, read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). It is also important to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ... and in order to write a clear question, [ask].

Comment: the function like refresh() in the official document of matplotlib in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update a plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random(20) # inital data set
f,ax = plt.subplots() # create the figure and plot
ax.plot(data) # plot initial data

for _ in range(10):
    data = np.random.random(20) # create new data
    ax.cla() # clear subplot's current data
    ax.plot(data) # plot new data

    plt.pause(0.01) # wait a few secs to allow plot to update 
    f.canvas.draw() # draw the plot again (in the same window)
```

The important bit here is to clear the current content and then draw again. For some reason to do with the way matplotlib handles plotting there needs to be a pause between the plot command and the draw command (or you have to flush the changes).

Comment: yeah,the command  "plt.pause()"  can achieve my expectation.But when i use multithreading  to plot and pause in the ax window at the same time,the program  can't work.So,there is other command to achieve the same function?

Comment: the specific codes and problems are showed in this web:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280558/python-ax-window-content-being-automatically-refreshed

Comment: @David you could also use f.canvas.flush_events() instead of plt.pause()

Comment: today i have used the  f.canvas.flush_events() achieving my expectation.thanks a lot

Comment: recently i find the program is not  stable. as it run,the mouse point becomes a  spinning circle.sometimes it is interrupted,and gets the error discription:    Tcl_AttemptSetObjLength called with shared object

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate